# Как вывести переменную до объявления её значения

Tags: php

Как вывести переменную до объявления её значения?

Пример:

```
echo $text;
// какой-то код
$text="Привет";
```

Comment: а что мешает сделать это в правильном порядке?

Comment: Структура сайта не позволяет, есть ли способ?

Comment: Скажите зачем вам это? Какие цели вы преследуете? Может вы просто выбрали не правильный подход?

Comment: если некая "структура сайта" не позволяет делать правильно, значит в топку такую структуру. То, что вы хотите - это, мягко говоря, чушь. 

И да, можно поподробнее - что и как конкретно не позволяет?

Comment: @Rammsteinik

> Как вывести переменную до объявления её значения?

Никак, ее же не существует

> Структура сайта не позволяет, есть ли способ?

Писать правильную архитектуру

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP интерпретируемый язык, код компилируется и выполняется построчно сверху вниз, раньше чем вы объявите переменную ее просто нет, вообще нет. Не путайте с компилируемыми языками, где вначале компилятор собирает все переменные.

Comment: в компилируемых языках такие фокусы тоже не очень-то приветствуются

Comment: мне кажется это не являетя признаком компилируемого или интерпретируемого языка, например в js это нормальный код:

    var a; 
    
    setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(a);
    });
    
    a="Hello world";